# Sendgrid Web API send 400 Message in single request

Tags: php, sendgrid

I want to send a job notification to the user (about 400+ user) via sendgrid rest API. Now I'm using a loop to make a request each user's email (Because email content should be unique/contain name).

First try:
When I using curl to make an API call inside loop email query, it's causing PHP execution time limit exceeded.

Second try:
I'm using `curl_multi_init` but still, have execution time limit issue.

So it's possible to make a sendgrid API call in a single request? I've searched some better way on sendgrid DOC, but nothing found.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Yes. You can. See here : https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html You can have multiple emails in the To field and add substitutions for the unique content, see here : https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Build/Add_Content/substitution_and_section_tags.html

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian-LaurenţiuPlesciuc for the answer, but doc says: "When you send to a list of recipients over SMTP API you can specify substitution tags specific to each recipient"
It's still possible when i'm using Web API?

Comment: Yes. Here are some more examples of how substitutions are used using X-SMTPAPI header (which is the old way, but it will give you an idea on how to use it) : https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/substitution_tags.html  The V3 mail send web api, has substitutions as well which you can send directly in the request.

Comment: @Sebastian-LaurenţiuPlesciuc Thank you. It's working now.